# How to merge two columns from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having a csv file that I did manipulations on it, I merged two different files using `pandas.merge`. But now, I have some columns that are called for example column_x and column_y.
So I want to merge these two columns to obtain one column.
By knowing that the two columns can be represented like this:

```
Column_x     Column_y
       2          2.1 
                    3
   4.322            4
       5
```

And then obtain either one of these two results:

```
Column  
     2  
     3    
 4.322 
     5
```

Or:

```
Column
     2.1 
     3
     4
     5
```

Either of these two results will satisfy me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.replace('', np.nan).Column_x.fillna(df.Column_y)
```

or

```
df.replace('', np.nan).Column_y.fillna(df.Column_x)
```

Respectively, these output:

```
0    2.000
1    3.000
2    4.322
3    5.00
```

and

```
0    2.1
1    3.0
2    4.0
3    5.0
```

If your blank "cells" in your dataframe are already `NaN`, you can go ahead and omit the `.replace('', np.nan)`

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
df.bfill(axis=1)

    Column_x    Column_y
0   2.100   2.1
1   3.000   NaN
2   4.322   4.0
3   5.000   NaN
```

Or

```
df.ffill(axis=1)

   Column_x Column_y
0   NaN     2.1
1   3.000   3.0
2   4.322   4.0
3   5.000   5.0
```

You can simply use `df.ffill(axis=1)['Column_x']` to achieve first result and `df.ffill(axis=1)['Column_y']` to achieve second result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```
df['Column'] = df['Column_x'].combine_first(df['Column_y'])
```

Output:

```
   Column_x  Column_y  Column
0     2.000       2.1   2.000
1       NaN       3.0   3.000
2     4.322       4.0   4.322
3     5.000       NaN   5.000
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is this:

```
df['Column']= df['Column_x'].replace('', np.NaN).fillna(df.Column_y)
```